# spring data + oracle + обновление ключа секции приведет к ее изменению

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

При попытке выполнить update c использованием Spring Data, я получаю ошибку

> Hibernate: select message0_.msg_id as msg_id1_2_0_, ....
>   message0_.status as status12_2_0_ from messages message0_ where
>   message0_.msg_id=?
>
> Hibernate: update messages set date_out=?,
>   date_rcv=?, date_send=?, document_id=?, msg_code=?, msg_filename=?,
>   msg_updated=?, owner=?, receiver=?, sender=?, status=? where msg_id=?
>     WARN http-nio-8080-exec-1
>   o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:137 - SQL Error: 14402, SQLState: 72000
>
> ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-1
>   o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:142 - ORA-14402: обновление ключа секции
>   приведет к ее изменению
>
> ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-1
>   o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl:39 - HHH000346: Error during managed
>   flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute
>   statement]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGES")
public class Message {

    /**Уникальный идентификатор записи*/
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "MSG_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long msgId;

    ////
    }

public interface MessageUpdateRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
}
```

Использую метод save() и передаю туда сущность.

Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка ?

Обновляю только 2 поля

```
@GetMapping(PATH_TO_RESOURCE_UPDATE)
    public void updateEntryBySysdate(@PathVariable Integer status){


        DtoMessage dtoMessage = DtoMessage.newBuilder()
                .msgId(1097101L)
                .status(100)
                .build();

        System.out.println();

        this.messageUpdateService.updateStatusIntoMessage(dtoMessage);

    }
```

из сервис слоя

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void updateStatusIntoMessage(DtoMessage statusMessage) {

        Message message = this.messageMapper.dtoMessageToMessage(statusMessage);

        this.messageUpdateRepository.save(message);

    }
}
```

Как я понимаю, я должен запросить все данные записи, которую я буду менять, затем изменить одно поле и эту сущность заново отправить в базу ?

Я запросил всю запись, изменил одно поле и отправил обратно, тогда все четко изменилось, но это долгий путь.

А если я создаю dto, просто указываю id , меняю одно поле и остальные поля null и затем конвертирую его в сущность и в таком виде оно отправляется в базу, то поэтому exception ?

То есть hibernate "не понимает" что поля которые null , не нужно обновлять, так как метод save() не распознает что мне нужно сделать ?

А если я не хочу так много действий:
- сначала запросить запись, потом изменить поле и отправить ее обратно в базу

как сделать метод для изменения лишь некоторых полей ?

**Обновление**

Мое решение вот такое, чтобы все работало (но ведь у меня сущности на 30 и более полей, а это сказывается на производительности)

```
 @Transactional
 @Override
 public void updateStatusIntoMessage(Long id, Integer status) {

    Message message = changeEntryByStatus(id, status);

    this.messageUpdateRepository.save(message);

}

/**изменение поля STATUS*/
private Message changeEntryByStatus (Long id, Integer status){

    DtoMessage dtoMessage = getEntryById(id);
    dtoMessage.setStatus(status);

    return this.messageMapper.dtoMessageToMessage(dtoMessage);
}

/**получение записи по ID*/
private DtoMessage getEntryById(Long id){

    Optional<Message> byId = this.messagesReadRepository.findById(id);
    Message messageById = byId.orElse(new Message());

    return this.messageMapper.messageToDtoMessage(messageById);
}
```

**Обновление**

Я пытаюсь использовать JPQL

```
/**обновление записи*/
public interface MessageUpdateRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("UPDATE Message m SET m.status = :status where m.msgId = :id")
    void updateEntity(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("status") Integer status);

}
```

но запись не меняется и ошибок в консоли не видно...?

**Нативная запись.**

```
 @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = "update messages set status = ?2 where msg_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateEntity(Long id, Integer status);
```

То же не отработала и нет ошибок

Comment: Связаный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1107793/217579

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости маппер dto в entity наполняет остальные поля null или поле по которой происходит секционирование устанавливается в тек дату-время если в dto null.

this.messageMapper.dtoMessageToMessage(statusMessage)

на самом деле странно что метод семантически обозначающий какую то мутацию принимает в качестве параметра какой то полузаполненный объект проекции мутируемого объекта, чтобы просто вызвать конвертор данных и сохранить в стиле crud...В общем я не удевлен что это в принципе когда то работало правильно до попытки введения секционирования(это я говорю о this.messageUpdateService.updateStatusIntoMessage(dtoMessage))

Скорей всего будет правелней, если метод this.messageUpdateService.updateStatusIntoMessage будет принимать или просто 2 параметра(id, status) или объект команду типа UpdateStatusCommand. Можно попробовать генерализировать его, но тут главное не зашиться в интерфейсах;)

То есть первый вариант выглядеть должен так

```
 @Transactional
 @Override
 public void updateStatusIntoMessage(Long id, Integer status) {
    Message message = this.messageUpdateRepository.loadById(id);
    message.setStatus(status);
    this.messageUpdateRepository.save(message);

}
```

Данный код должен работать, если не работает то это мистика, и я бы влючил полною трасировку как спринга так и хибера...потому что спринг как бы то нибыло а должен исполнять свою ответвенность по генерации репозитория и инекцирования его в сервис

Все эти конвертации из Entity в Dto и обратно это конечно клево, но в сервисном слое точно не нужно...Есть такой подход когда пытаются отделить инфраструктурные Entity от домена - но если это и делать то явно не анемичной моделью, которая у вас присутвует в полный рост.

Видно что вы пытаетесь отделить чтение от записи на уровне классов(движение в направлении CQRS?)...это хорошее направление, но если это так то командная часть вообще не должна смотреть ни на messagesReadRepository ни на messageMapper. Так как это зона чтения которая может быть "в конечном итоге консистента", а для обеспечения проверок это не доспустимо. И так же для зоны чтения нет границ в связанности объектов(компания запросто может выйти на сущность продажа, если она так или иначе с ней связана), что для зоны записи не допустимо(иначе получим просто безумно связанный код монолита распределенного или физического - не важно)

И еще стоит обратить внимание на возможность обновлять данные имя только ссылку(идентификатор)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference-with-jpa

Comment: "поле по которой происходит секционирование"  - это что значит ?

Comment: Кстати, я запросил всю запись, изменил одно поле и отправил обратно, тогда все четко изменилось, но это долгий путь.

Comment: да, все остальные поля в null устанавливались

Comment: Поле которое учавствует в функции секционирования таблицы в оркл. Поищите вопрос секционирования в гугле, это достаточно обширная тема, но если в крадце данное поле менять нельзя. Скорее всего эта какая нибуть дата отправки

Comment: По поводу долгого пути не понял что вы имели ввиду. Могу только сказать что для хибернейта это нормальный сценарий - прочесть а потом поменять и сохранить. Если делать систему на основе агрегатов то оно все равно так происходит, потому что для проверки инварианта агрегата нужно поднимать его весь, за исключением может быть коллекций.

Comment: Я несколько изменил ответ, предложил сиггатуру метода, которая выведет вас на прозрачную реализацию

Comment: Таким образом, я запрашиваю запись по id, затем меняю и отправляю дальше на изменение. Это работает. Но что значит : " this.messageUpdateService.updateStatusIntoMessage будет принимать или просто 2 параметра или объект команду типа UpdateStatusCommand"  - можете пример написать, я не понял что за решение вы предложили

Comment: Я и имел в виду ваш вариант  public void updateStatusIntoMessage(Long id, Integer status). По поводу обновления через отдельный метод в репозитории тоже вариант, правда при этом вы уводите часть логики в хранилище, но в вашем случае это меньшее из зол(30 атрибутов это конечно тяжко). Странно что не работает, к сожалению сейчас нет возможности перепроверить. Попробуйте включить логи sql с параметрами в hibernate

Comment: обновил еще раз ответ с примером, как я это видел с первых коментариев...