# После секционирования таблиц ошибка: "ORA-14402: обновление ключа секции приведет к ее изменению"

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-jpa, oracle11g

Был написан код с использованием Spring Data Jpa. Поставщик Jpa - Hibernate.
Были созданы таблицы, в которые сохранялись и читались данные.

Когда в таблицы по некоторым полям было добавлено секционирование, стала появляться ошибка:

> ORA-14402: обновление ключа секции приведет к ее изменению

Как работать с такими бизнес-объектами из Java?
Кто работал с такими таблицами ?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Из описания ошибки:

```
$ oerr ora 14402
```

> 14402, 00000, "updating partition key column would cause a partition change"
>   // *Cause:  An UPDATE statement attempted to change the value of a partition
>   //          key column causing migration of the row to another partition
>   // *Action: Do not attempt to update a partition key column or make sure that
>   //          the new partition key is within the range containing the old
>   //          partition key.

следует, что изменение ключа секционирования приведёт к изменению секции. То есть, физическому перемещению записи(ей) из одной секции в другую, что по умолчанию не допускается. Проверьте эти измнения на соответствие бизнес логике.

---

```sql
create table ptab1 (id number, created date)
partition by range (created) interval (numtoyminterval (1,'year')) (
    partition part2019 values less than (date'2020-01-01'),
    partition part2020 values less than (date'2021-01-01'));

insert into ptab1 
    select 1, date'2019-06-30' from dual union all  
    select 2, date'2020-04-30' from dual;  

update ptab1 set created=date'2020-01-30' where id=1;
```

> ORA-14402: updating partition key column would cause a partition change

Если есть уверенность, что так и задумано, то включите для таблицы перемещение записей:

```sql
select table_name, row_movement
from user_tables where table_name = upper ('ptab1');

TABLE_NAME       ROW_MOVEMENT    
---------------- ----------------
PTAB1            DISABLED        

alter table ptab1 enable row movement;

Table PTAB1 altered.

update ptab1 set created=date'2020-01-30' where id=1;

1 row updated.
```